# From Datagridview To Excel - It Doesn't Save My Numerical Values

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export

It's my export code from datagridview to excel file:

```
            for (int s = 0; s < dgw.Rows.Count - 1; s++)
            {
                for (int s2 = 0; s2 < dgw.Columns.Count - 1; s2++)
                {
                    ea.Cells[s + 2, s2 + 1] = dgw.Rows[s].Cells[s2].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Remove 'ToString'.  Cell is probably of type object, so you should set there orignal value, not serialized to string.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: the error is here: 'for (int s2 = 0; s2 < dgw.Columns.Count - 1; s2++)' Remove -1 or change < to  <=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here: `for (int s2 = 0; s2 < dgw.Columns.Count - 1; s2++)` 
Remove `-1` or change `<` to `<=`